# Error creating event - The property 'address' does not exist

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Just started repeatedly getting this error, with the same request structure the app was successfully using before to create an event using the Microsoft Graph API -

"The property 'address' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.EmailAddress'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."

The "attendees" property of the failing request looks like the following:

"attendees":[{"emailAddress":{"address":"emailaddress@host.com"},"type":"required"}]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And when I just use the example request in the docs with the address changed, I get this error - "The property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Location'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type." (Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Looks like the issue is just with v1.0, not beta.

Comment: I also just started experiencing this issue with the v1 endpoint. Getting back two different errors from v1.0/me/events and v1.0/me/sendMail Error 1:
"The property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Recipient'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."

Error 2:
"The property 'address' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.EmailAddress'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."

Comment: There also seems to have been a change on beta where when I do successfully create an event, it returns the property "uid" instead of "iCalUId".

Comment: Looks like the v1.0 issues have been fixed.

Comment: There was an issue with Exchange workloads for several hours yesterday. It has since been resolved.